# Powershell: Copy selected files in subfolders

Tags: file, powershell, directory, subdirectory

I have a folder `c:\graphics` (root) and a program that creates subfolders e.g. `aa`, `bm`, `czx`, `mjpq`, `zz` (I have many subfolders, the length is variable).

In each subfolder, I have 26 files and one folder. For example, `aa` folder has: `aa_000.jpg`, `aa_001.jpg`, ..., `aa_023.jpg`; other two files `aa_360.jpg`, `aa.html` and a folder. The complete path is `C:\graphics\aa\aa_360`.

I need to move 24 files (`aa_000.jpg`, `aa_001.jpg`, ..., `aa_023.jpg`) in subfolder `c:\graphics\aa\aa_360` and also equal to each subfolder.

Another example is `c:\graphics\mjpq\mjpq_360`, should have `mjpq_000.jpg`, ..., `mjpq_023.jpg`.

I started the script, thinking move all `.jpg` (25 files) in the subfolder (later, I had to think like extract the `xxx_360.jpg`) but it doesn't work:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\graphics -rec | where-object {$_.extension -match "jpg"} | ForEach-object {$newPath =(Get-Location).toString()+(Get-Location).ToString().SubString(10)+"_360"); Move-Item $_.FullName $newPath}
```

but `Get-Location` doesn't find the file path.

---

NOTE: I found a solution that is working, but it throw some errors in the console:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\graphics -rec | where-object {$_.extension -match "jpg" -and (!($_.name -like "*360*"))} | ForEach-Object {$newPath =($_.DirectoryName).toString()+($_.DirectoryName).ToString().SubString(10)+"_360"; Move-Item $_.FullName $newPath}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can simplify this to:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\graphics -rec *.jpg | Move-Item -Dest {$_.Directory.FullName + "\" +
    $_.Directory.Name + "_360\" } -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-whatif` if the suggested move operations look correct.

Comment: Working. i found errors, but it work. Create a  file more ;). Thanks

Comment: I think you need the -include parameter in the Get-ChildItem command?

Comment: @Ant This uses the -filter parameter by position.

Comment: Ah great - still new to powershell (as you could probably already tell!)